# Match and extract special word in Dart

Tags: dart

I tried to manipulate a text to match and extract special or some words in Dart. For example:
I want to check matching of words ends with a given word

```
String oldText = "website or show me to";
String newText = "show me to tell";

if (oldText.trim().endsWith(newText.trim())) {
   final extractText = oldText.trim().substring(newText.length);
   print(extractText);
} else {
   print("Not matched");
}
```

I want to extract only word - **"tell"** so how can I do it? Need to use Regular expression?

Comment: You want to find out if a string ends with a specific word and then return that word if it does?

Comment: Yes that is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here.  I've implemented a regex which will check that tell is followed by end of line `$`.  The regex is probably easier than any other method you might try, plus it's easy to change if conditions change.

```
void main() {
  
  String oldText = "website or show me to";
  String newText = "show me to tell";
  RegExp parser = RegExp(r"tell$");
  
  if (parser.hasMatch(oldText)) {
    print(parser.stringMatch(oldText).toString());
  } else {
    print("Not matched");
  }
  
  if (parser.hasMatch(newText)) {
    print(parser.stringMatch(newText).toString());
  } else {
    print("Not matched");
  }
  
}
```

And here is an example where I have removed the check to a function and also set it up so that you can dynamically generate the regex:

```
void main() {
  
  String oldText = "website or show me to";
  String newText = "show me to tell";
  String test = "tell";
  RegExp parser = RegExp(test+r"$");
  
  print(checkMatch(oldText, parser));
  print(checkMatch(newText, parser));
  
}
checkMatch(text, parser) {
  
  if (parser.hasMatch(text)) {
    return(parser.stringMatch(text).toString());
  } else {
    return("Not matched");
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks will try your code now.

Comment: Just test it and output was "tell" but not what I wanted. thanks.

Comment: Your question says: `I want to extract only word - "tell" `.  What do you really want?

Comment: Sorry what i tried to explain my problem was not clear. I meant i want the regular expression to be able to check if there are any words matched between newText like "show me to"  instead of "tell" and oldText. if it does match any, substring or extract some unmatched words like tell from newText. I used continuous speech recognition to listen any voice and get result that would be appended to a previous result because the speech recognition occasionally set a new result without appending them in a few seconds. Sorry for my bad English grammar.

Comment: So you want to compare two strings (oldText, newText) and extract the unmatched words from the second string (newText)?

Comment: Oh yes  you get me right. That's what I meant.

Comment: Does order matter?  `website or show me ` and `show me to tell`, the common words are `show me`, but what if you had `website or me show` and `show me to tell`.  The same words are still common, but they're not in the same order.  What do you do in this case?

Comment: Okay. The common words between two texts are **show me to** so I will remove the same ones from the new text since the same ones are already in the old text and then append it to the unmatched text from the new text.

Comment: Look at the texts I gave in example.  They are slightly different than what you provided in the question.  The common words are `me` and `show` in both examples, but they are in different order.  Does this make a difference?

Comment: Okay I think it is really hard to follow orders since they are in different orders. Is there any way to track the same words from start till end?

Comment: You can do it with order mattering or not mattering, just whichever you want to do let me know.